# How to reload a FileImage in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Let's say I have an image on the device's disk and load it on the screen providing its path to a `FileImage`.

I edit that image and save it on the same path expecting calling the `setState(() {})` function will reload it. But it doesn't.

I tried clearing the image cache by calling `imageCache.clear()` function and also `imageProvider.evict()` but no difference.

If I close that page and open it again, I see the updated images.

I assume the images that are being displayed on the screen are in the memory, if my assumption is correct, how to reload it?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround.
I had to store the edited image to a new path, update the FileImage path to the new path by setting the state and then delete the image in the old path.
It's not the most efficient way to do it, but for now it works for me

Comment: Ok thanks, really weird  that we can't force a reload. they should add an extra parameter reload: true/false to avoid the cache.

Comment: Based on [a similar GitHub comment (and its reply)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17419#issuecomment-408026214), it sounds like you might need to wait for the caches to release the old image.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm a bit late, but I used this workaround:

```
_tmpImageFile.existsSync() ? Image.memory(
  Uint8List.fromList(_tmpImageFile.readAsBytesSync()),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
) : Container(),
```

Answer (score 3):

This is also working for me:

```
Image previewImage = Image.file(
    File(scenePreviewFilename),
);
```

And when pressing a button or something just evict the cached image from [imageCache](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html) like this:

```
setState(() {
    imageCache.evict(previewImage.image, includeLive: true);
});
```

PS: I had some issues getting this to work(similar to the initial post) because I was generating the image in another thread and the image was loaded before it was generated, resulting in the imageCache appearing not to have an effect ... so make sure you are not in this race situation.

Answer (score 3):

Already tested - Adding the both image cache commands will solve the problem.

```
            imageCache.clear();
              imageCache.clearLiveImages();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Would changing the key of the Image do the trick?

Set a key to the image

```
Image.file(
    _imageFile,
    key: _key,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

and change the key every time you change _imageFile, let's set it to timestamp for example

```
setState(() {
    _imageFile = newImageFile;
    _key = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
});
```

Comment: @JavidNoutash Darn, sorry that I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly workaround, but it works for me. Here we're resetting image cache + force reloading image from disk:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final imageKey = GlobalKey();
  bool forceLoad = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final app = MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: forceLoad
          ? Image.memory(currentFile.readAsBytesSync(), key: imageKey)
          : Image.file  (currentFile, key: imageKey),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () async {
            await (imageKey.currentWidget as Image).image.evict(); // reset cache for current image
            setState(() {
              forceLoad = true;                                    // reloading current image from disk
            });
          },
        )
      )
    );
    forceLoad = false;
    return app;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were missing step 2. Full explanation [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17419#issuecomment-620831027).

1. call `imageCache.clear();` and then `imageCache.clearLiveImages();` when the new image needs to be reloaded.
2. Add a value key in the image widget to ensure the new image gets rebuilt

`Image(image: FileImage(File(pathName)), key: ValueKey(File(pathName).lengthSync()))`

The image should reload after.

Answer (score 0):

Just another (late) workaround

```
  ImageProvider loadImage(String filePath) {
    final File file = File(filePath);
    return MemoryImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the solution.

just set `cacheWidth: 50` and `cacheHeight: 50` and if work good for me.

here is my code that worked for me

```
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: Image.file(
                  File(logic.companyLogo.value),
                  cacheWidth: 50,
                  cacheHeight: 50,
                ).image,
              )
```